# configure Sensu to collect metrics from Prometheus; using ruby

Tags: ruby, kubernetes, prometheus

I set up Prometheus in kubernetes to get the metrics. Now, I'm working on getting Sensu to monitor the metrics from prometheus.

Answer (score 2):

I found with a quick reasearch on google that in github there's a collector for Sensu:
https://github.com/portertech/sensu-prometheus-collector#sensu-prometheus-collector

Comment: thanks, but I was more looking for writing checks in ruby

Comment: https://rubygems.org/gems/sensu-plugins-prometheus-checks/versions/3.1.3